# Parsing invalid XSD in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xerces

I have an invalid `XSD` file and I'm trying to parse it in Java. I'm getting `SAXParseException` only once when I try to parse my invalid `XSD`. Second and all subsequent attempts do not produce `SAXParseException`. I do not expect there is a bug in Java, but also cannot comprehend the behavior, expecting `SAXParseException` each time. Any help or explanation would be very welcome.

There is a Java source here:

```
package com.myxsd;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class ParseXSD {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        String file = ParseXSD.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/myxsd/myxsd.xsd").getFile();
        try {
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File(file)); 
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        // sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        try {      
            // no exception is thrown during second attempt to get schema
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File(file)); 
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();            
            validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
            // sample.xml gets validated without any issues
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(ParseXSD.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/myxsd/sample.xml").getFile()));
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    private static class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

        private boolean isValid = true;

        public boolean isValid() {
            return this.isValid;
        }

        @Override
        public void warning(SAXParseException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void error(SAXParseException exc) throws SAXParseException {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            this.isValid = false;
            throw exc;
        }

        @Override
        public void fatalError(SAXParseException exc) throws SAXParseException {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            this.isValid = false;
            throw exc;
        }
    }
}
```

and invalid myxsd.xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:n1="www.myns.com/XMLSchema">

    <xs:import namespace="www.myns.com/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="xsd/notexistingfile.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="mytype" type="n1:mytype">
    </xs:element>   

</xs:schema>
```

Uncommenting the line on which `new SchemaFactory` is created workarounds the issue, but I would expect that `SchemaFactory` should be rather used as singleton.

Not only that `SAXParseException` is not thrown in the second attempt, but also validation can be performed and it is successful in case of the following sample.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mytype></mytype>
```

The output when running the program follows:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/workspace/XSD_PARSING/bin/com/myxsd/myxsd.xsd; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 45; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'n1:mytype' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.myxsd.ParseXSD.main(ParseXSD.java:22)
```

Instance of `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.SimpleXMLSchema` contains the following list of features:

```
"http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema/augment-psvi" true
"http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error" false
"http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing" true
"http://apache.org/xml/features/honour-all-schemaLocations" false
"http://apache.org/xml/features/validate-annotations" false
"http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking" true
"http://apache.org/xml/features/internal/tolerate-duplicates" false
"http://apache.org/xml/features/generate-synthetic-annotations" false
"http://apache.org/xml/features/namespace-growth" false
"http://www.oracle.com/feature/use-service-mechanism" false
"http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" false
```

Comment: Could you check what kind of schema gets returned from the second call?

Comment: Instance of com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.SimpleXMLSchema is returned by subsequent call.

Comment: Im getting errors on both cases. What JRE are you executing your code on? Also are you looking for a way to ignore invalid imports or are just curious why you arent getting an exception?

Comment: I tried to build and run this example in Java 6 and also in Java 8, both on Windows. I am curious about the reason, but also it is a possible source of issues as my tests pass even in case when they should fail.

Comment: @stepasite I tested on SE 6, 7 and 8. Got both catch statements on all 3. Are you sure your reading your output correctly?

Comment: @ug_ Thanks for investigation. I debugged the code line after line in Eclipse. I am wondering whether location of XSD file might play role in this.

Comment: Could you somehow investigate what's inside that instance?

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks for the help. I added complete Java source code and stack trace when running the program. Anyway it is intended that referenced `XSD` does not exist.

Comment: Unless I'm severely missing something, you do not show or tell how your second execution happens. Your code suggests it would have to happen from a second run of your program, i.e. in a whole new JVM process. Surely you are not getting this behavior on alternate JVM executions? If not, the part of your code most germane to the problem is missing here.

Comment: @EricS: Thanks for looking into this. The example is complete. My question is not related to second run of the program. It is sufficient enough to run it once.

Please notice that program tries to load invalid myxsd.xsd twice by calling `Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File(file));`, but only in the first attempt `SAXParseException` is caught and printed to the output.

Comment: @stepasite: oh, I see, I'd thought you were talking about the validate call itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what must be going on is that SchemaFactory is caching the schema. So when you try to read it a second time, it uses the cached copy.

I'm not particularly familiar with this specific API, having used the Xerces xni interfaces more, but I think they share the same underlying implementation,and I know Xerces can and does in some circumstances do schema caching. I'm inclined to wonder why a SchemaFactory would even be needed unless it were meant to do some cross-schema book-keeping like caching or allowing you to build up a schema from parts.

My advice would be to download a copy of the JDK source and step into the sf.newSchema call with a debugger...I'd be willing to bet you will see the schema cached. I'm not sure what implementation class the JDK uses but if you look at the [Xerces one](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/trunk/src/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/validation/XMLSchemaFactory.java), the newSchema method here (which the abstract base class SchemaFactory method will end up calling, if this implementation were installed) does instantiate a GrammarPool.